# What is my syntax error in this c code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have just written some C code for checking for a checkmate (in chess), but I really can't understand what's wrong with my syntax, this is the compile error:

```
main.c:2:30: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'board'           
int is_check(const char[][8] board,int i,int j){                      

                               ^                                                                                                                                                  main.c:117:27: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'board'         

int check(const char[][8] board)
```

and this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int is_check(const char[][8] board,int i,int j){
int row = i;
int clmn = j;
//check clmn , up
  do{
  i--;
  }
  while(board[i][j] == 'z');
   if(i>=0){
  if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
    return 1;
   }
}

i = row;//init

//check clmn , down
  do{
  i++;
 }
while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(i<8){
 if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
   return 1;
   }
}

i = row;//init

//check row , up
 do{
  j--;
  }
  while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j>=0){
  if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
    return 1;
   }
}

j = clmn;//init

//check row , down
 do{
  j++;
  }
  while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j<8){
  if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
    return 1;
   }
 }

j = clmn;//init

//check orib!4
do{
j++;
i++;
}
while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j<8 && i<8){
if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
return 1;
}
}

j = clmn;
i = row;

//check orib!1
do{
j++;
i--;
}
while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j<8 && i>=0){
if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
return 1;
}
}

j = clmn;
i = row;

//check orib!3
do{
j--;
i++;
}
while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j>=0 && i<8){
if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
return 1;
}
}

j = clmn;
i = row;

//check orib!2
do{
j--;
i--;
}
while(board[i][j] == 'z');
if(j>=0 && i>=0){
if(board[i][j] == 'H'){
return 1;
}
}
return 0;

}//end func

int check(const char[][8] board)
{
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(;i<8;i++){
 for(;j<8;j++){
  if(board[i][j] == 'q')
   return is_check(board,i,j);
}
}
return 0;
}

int main(){
char x[8][8] ={{'R','z','B','Q','H','z','q','R'},
               {'A','A','A','A','z','z','A','A'},
               {'z','z','z','d','z','z','D','z'},
               {'z','z','z','z','z','z','z','b'},
               {'z','z','z','z','a','z','z','z'},
               {'a','z','z','a','z','z','z','z'},
               {'z','a','a','z','z','a','a','a'},
               {'r','d','b','z','h','z','z','r'}};
printf("%d",check(x));
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it should be

```
const char board[][8];
```